# Using schema.org WebPage and data-vocabulary.org Breadrumb together

Tags: html, metadata, breadcrumbs, schema.org, microdata

I want to semantically enhance my HTML markup by adding elements from the [schema.org WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) vocabulary including semantic markup for the breadcrumb navigation. According to the definition I should use [schema.org BreadcrumbList](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) to achieve this.

When looking at [Google's documentation about adding structured data for Breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs) though, they explicitly state that the schema.org markup for breadcrumbs is not yet supported.

[image: Google statement about that they don't support breadcrumb markup with schema.org yet]

Instead, the apparently older definition for a [data-vocabulary.org Breadcrumb](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb/) should be applied. This seems to be due to the fact, that the [schema.org BreadcrumbList is still disputed](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/10). Actually Google parses schema.org BreadcrumbList markup in their [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) but don't use it for nice representation in the search results like they do for breadcrumbs annoted using the data-vocabulary.org Breadcrumb definition.

However, it would be nice to bring together both worlds and have semantic markup for webpage and breadcrumbs. The best I was able to come up with looks like this (using `itemref` to prevent needing to nest each `Breadcrumb` into the other):

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <h1 itemprop="name">George Orwell</h1>
  <p itemprop="description">Eric Arthur Blair (25 June 1903 – 21 January
  1950), who used the pen name George Orwell, was an English novelist,
  essayist, journalist and critic.</p>

  <nav itemprop="breadcrumb">
    <ul itemscope>
      <li id="bc1"itemscope itemref="bc2"
        itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="http://example.com/books" itemprop="url">
          <span itemprop="title">Books</span>
        </a> ›
      </li>
      <li id="bc2" itemscope itemprop="child" itemref="bc3"
        itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">>
        <a href="http://example.com/books/authors" itemprop="url">
          <span itemprop="title">Authors</span>
        </a> ›
      </li>
      <li id="bc3" itemscope itemprop="child"
        itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">>
        <a href="http://example.com/books/authors/orwell" itemprop="url">
          <span itemprop="title">George Orwell</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

The `itemscope` attribute on the `<ul>` is needed so the subsequent breadcrumbs with `itemprop="child"` are not interpreted as properties of `WebPage`.

When I throw this code at the Structured Data testing tool, all data is recognised as I want it to be, but there are warnings for the undefined `ul` item.

Is it safe to ignore these errors? Are there other approaches or even best practices to solve the problem? What about future-proofness: would it be wise to use this kind of code on a website that may not be updated for years?

Answer (score 1):

When testing your markup, [Google’s Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) doesn’t seem to report any errors or warnings. It says "All good" for every item.

Your use of Microdata is valid. You are adding an item without type, which does not have any content (because no properties are added).

Using Schema.org’s [`breadcrumb` property](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) seems to be appropriate, as one of its expected types is *Text*. So Schema.org consumers would extract only the text content of the child items, no URLs:

> Books › > Authors › > George Orwell

---

I don’t think that the [linked issue](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/10) is the reason why Google does not support Schema.org’s [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList): the issue is from 2012, but the `BreadcrumbList` type was [added](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html) only a few months ago (2014-12-11) to Schema.org.
The issue is about using the `breadcrumb` property without a type (which did not exist back then), which is not ideal because this does not allow to specify metadata for each breadcrumb (e.g., its URL).

---

The future-proof way would be to use *both* vocabularies for breadcrumbs. The Microdata syntax makes this [hard/impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669), but the RDFa syntax allows this (however, the odd requirement from Data-Vocabulary.org that the breadcrumbs have to be nested might require markup changes).