# Microdata format for showing an event with multiple date/time

Tags: schema.org, microdata

With Microdata, what is the best way to represent an event page with multiple date/time booking options? There will be occasions when the event page only has one booking option, i.e one set date/time, no alternative, does this require a different method?

```html
<section>
  <h1>Tennis Lessons</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Book Tickets for
      <time datetime="2001-05-15 19:00">May 15</time>
    </li>
    <li>Book Tickets for
      <time datetime="2001-05-16 19:00">May 16</time>
    </li>
    <li>Book Tickets for
      <time datetime="2001-05-17 19:00">May 17</time>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Or is this the wrong way to approach it and the `events` are children of a `product`?

```html
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Tennis Lessons</h1>
  <ol>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">Book Tickets for
      <time datetime="2001-05-15 19:00">May 15</time>
    </li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">Book Tickets for
      <time datetime="2001-05-16 19:00">May 16</time>
    </li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">Book Tickets for
      <time datetime="2001-05-17 19:00">May 17</time>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

In this case, on a booking confirmation page, it would then be correct to wrap the whole section in `event` Microdata as it then only has one possible date/time option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org defines that an [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) happens "at a certain time". So each lesson should be represented by its own `Event` item.

If you can book a lesson on your page, you may want to use the [`offers` property](http://schema.org/offers) and provide an [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) for each `Event`.

The nesting in your second snippet (`Event` items inside the `Product` item) has no influence on the Microdata ([example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82196/17633)). You have to use a property (within the `itemprop` attribute) if you want to connect Microdata items.
While you could use `Product` to represent the fact that you provide the service of tennis lessons, it seems that the [`Product` type](http://schema.org/Event) is missing a suitable property to reference an `Event` item. The typical solution would be to use both types, but Microdata is rather [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669) in that regard (it works better with RDFa).

If you want to provide data that is the same for all events, you could make use of the `itemref` attribute (instead of repeating it for each event).

So a basic structure could be this:

```html
<section>
  <h1>Tennis Lessons</h1>
  <p itemprop="description" id="event-desc">…</p>
  <ol>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="event-desc">
      <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="event-desc">
      <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```