# Semantic HTML elements for adding custom annotation data

Tags: html, semantic-web, schema.org, rdfa

Suppose I have an HTML paragraph that I'm interested in annotating (i.e. add some context that shouldn't be displayed, just add meaning to the text)

```
<p>The ultimate measure of a man is not where he stands 
in moments of <tag data="some custom annotation">comfort and convenience</tag>,
but where he stands at times of challenge and controversy.</p>
```

What is the right semantic tag that should be used in this case?

Comment: 1. Who is supposed to make use of the annotations? Only you? 2. Do the annotations only consist of plain text? 3. You tagged this with [tag:schema.org] -- Why? Does it have to use types/properties from the vocabulary Schema.org somehow? 4. You also tagged it with [tag:rdfa] -- why? Is the solution required to use RDFa? 5. As you tagged it with [tag:semantic-web], does the solution have to be based on RDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific tag for this case, specifying semantic meaning without showing the content. This is done with the `meta` tag with `itemprop` and `content` properties, and is well explained in the Getting Started section of [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html):

> 3c. Missing/implicit information: use the meta tag with content
>
> Sometimes, a web page has information that would be valuable to mark
>   up, but the information can't be marked up because of the way it
>   appears on the page. The information may be conveyed in an image (for
>   example, an image used to represent a rating of 4 out of 5) or a Flash
>   object (for example, the duration of a video clip), or it may be
>   implied but not stated explicitly on the page (for example, the
>   currency of a price).
>
> In these cases, use the meta tag along with the content attribute to
>   specify the information. Consider this example—the image shows users a
>   4 out of 5 star rating:
>
> ```
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
>   <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
>   <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
>   <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
>   Based on 25 user ratings
> </div>
> ```
>
> Here is the example again with the rating information marked up.
>
> ```
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
>   <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
>   <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
>   <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
>     <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
>     <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
>     <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
>     Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> This technique should be used sparingly. Only use meta with content for information that cannot otherwise be marked up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a specific HTML tag, but rather semantic annotation. You have two options: [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)) and [RDFa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa).

Both have [similar capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957902/microdata-vs-rdfa) and are understood by search engine crawlers. That said Google is a supported of Microdata.

For ready-to-use examples you can refer to [schema.org website](http://schema.org). Each term definition show usage with both serializations. Your HTML could be:

### Microdata

```
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  The ultimate measure of a man is not where he stands in moments of 
  <span itemprop="description">comfort and convenience</span>,
  but where he stands at times of challenge and controversy.
</p>
```

### RDFa

```
<p vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
  The ultimate measure of a man is not where he stands in moments of 
  <span property="description">comfort and convenience</span>,
  but where he stands at times of challenge and controversy.
</p>
```

As you can see I simply use `<span>` to encapsulate annotated text. Other that that RDFa and Microdata aren't that different.

Also, do have a look at [RDF Translator app](http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/). It will help you fiddle with your annotations.

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant because it doesn't address my specific need for an annotation. This isn't a person, or a description, I just want to add semantic annotation to a piece of text.

Comment: Then I find your question incomplete and the tags used misleading. The Person is just an example. This is how you would annotate markup in the Semantic Web. You define a boundary of the featured object (`itemscope`/`typeof`) and inside annotate the objects attributes (`itemprop`/`property`).

Comment: Please expand your question so that your intent is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the "Custom Data Attributes". For example: `<p data-custom-name="any-value">...</p>`.

See:
https://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes