# typeof vs. itemprop and itemscope

Tags: html, markup, structured-data

I have always used `typeof` for structured data. Recently, I found out that we can also use `itemprop` and `itemscope` for the exact same purposes.

I know Schema.org is trendy right now but can anyone explain to me why should/should not switch from using `typeof` to `itemprop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof` is an attribute from **RDFa**.
`itemprop` and `itemscope` are attributes from **Microdata**.

So your question really is: *Should I use Microdata or RDFa?*

Both syntaxes are similar, and both can be used for Schema.org. See my [comparison between Microdata and RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669).

If you are happy with RDFa, there is no reason to switch to Microdata, unless you know of and care about a consumer (e.g., a search engine) that supports Microdata but not RDFa. The sponsors of Schema.org (Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, Yandex) usually support JSON-LD, Microdata, and RDFa.