# Rich Snippet recipe image not appearing in search results

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am having a [recipe blog](http://www.cheenachatti.com/recipe/sukhiyan-preparation-kerala-style/) for which the Google Rich Snippet testing tool returns a good [testing result](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://www.cheenachatti.com/recipe/sukhiyan-preparation-kerala-style/).

But in Google search I am not getting a thumbnail of the food. I have configured everything properly. For the last 2 weeks I am struggling to fix this.

Should I use the hRecipe format instead of http://schema.org/Recipe? Is schema.org included in Google recipes search?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893527/google-rich-snippets-for-a-recipe), it’s saying to use data-vocabulary.org instead of schema.org. Which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the google rich snippet testing tool gives you a good result, I think you should wait until it comes to the search result page properly. I search for "sukhiyan preparation" and Google SERP gives me this

[image]

This link http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1093493 says sometimes it needs more than 1-2 months to make the rich snippet appears.