# Is there an alternative for facebook og meta tags?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a list of events ***in one page***.

Next to each event there is a facebook share icon which has to share the title, description and image of the corresponding event. But here I can not use the og meta tags since all the share icons are in the same page.
I also used sharer.php?s=100%p[title]=test.... but this also did not show the title and other info.

Please help me

Comment: for those seeking information related to the general question asked here see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402528/opengraph-or-schema-org

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative as such - however as a work-around you could share a different URL, where the meta-tags are updated...

For example - for each share icon specify the URL as http://www.example.com/page/?event=11

Then in your favourite server side technology (PHP, ASP, .NET etc) pick up the event parameter and output the appropriate OG tags for each event.

----- Update as requested in comments to add PHP example -----

So based on the suggestion above that you initiate each Facebook share button specifying the URL with a parameter of ?event=x where x is a unique ID. In your PHP you could then have an array of meta tags for each event, e.g.:

```
$OGTags = array():
$OGTags[1]['description'] = 'This is the description for the first event';
$OGTags[1]['image'] = 'http://www.example.com/image/image.jpg'; // URL for an image related to the first event
$OGTags[2]['description'] = 'This is a description for the second event';
$OGTAgs[2]['image'] = 'http://www.example.com/image/image2.jpg'; // URL for an image related to the second event
```

Then where you currently output your OG tags you need to get the content from the array.

First check for the $_GET['event'] parameter:

```
$event = isset($_GET['event']) ? $_GET['event'] : '1'; // Use the first descriptor as a default in case parameter not specified
```

Then in the meta tags themselves update so they get the values from the PHP array:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $OGTAgs[$event]['image']" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $OGTAgs[$event]['description']" />
```

This should give you a good steer to implement it in your project.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but could you please clarify more ?

Comment: Ok - so imagine your events listing page is found at: www.example.com/events/

If you were to share that URL with Facebook it would pick up the OG meta tag data in your page and it would be the same, regardless of which event's share button has been pressed.

If you change the share buttons so each has a unique parameter - e.g. www.example.com/events/?event=1 or ?event=2 etc you can then use a server-side programming language to detect this parameter and output different meta tags for the OG data. 

Does this help? If not let me know which programming languages you use.

Comment: I guess I did something like that..I have did an ajax request on each share icon click so to change the meta tags, but this didnt works..Anyway I do wish that you give an example.. Iam using PHP (codeigniter)

Comment: AJAX wouldn't work as Facebook's crawler doesn't execute Javascript. I'll add a PHP example above now.

Comment: I will do your suggested solution and tell you about the results.