# How to add microformats in wordpress blog post without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, microformats

I am running a blogging tips niche blog -http://bloghelpline.com Here I read a lot about recent semantic web update in Google in the name of Hummingbird Algorithm. And, according to the new search algorithm update, it insist the webmasters to use microformats on their blog to improve search engine visibility. I didn't find any plugin stuffing Microformats, is there any way to add microformats to a wordpress blog post manually? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page#Specifications) are nothing more than defined `class` and `rel` values, basically.

So when you want to use a specific Microformat, look it up in the wiki and see how it has to be marked up.

In WordPress, depending on the Microformat and your content, you could add it to the HTML of your theme or as HTML in each post.

Comment: Thanks sir! I got another doubt(s), that there are 3 Semantic Markups: 1. Microdata, Microformats and RDFa. Which one is best? and is it possible to use all the three in my web document?Do other search engines have any markups like this?

Comment: @MothiVenkatesh: Yes, you can [use all three syntaxes at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17589792/1591669). There is not a "best" if you don’t have specific requirements. See my answer about [differences between Microdata and RDFa](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633), and a [superficial comparison of Microdata, Microformats, and RDFa](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/166669/63183).