# Schema.org vs. OG meta in head

Tags: schema.org, facebook-opengraph, html-head

Is there a difference between doing the OG metadata in the head of your HTML for say Facebook and Google?

If you add Schema.org markup to the body of your HTML document is it redundant to have OG data in the head? Is there an advantage to one over the other? Schema.org markup does not explicitly use meta property etc.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. -- Schema.org and Open Graph Protocol are vocabularies. Both can be used with RDFa (where the `property` attribute comes from). Both can be used in the `head` and/or in the `body`. -- Could you clarify?

Comment: HI Unor.  If I specify an image for an article or WebPage using Schema and I use OG data to do the same thing that is not redundant?  Would you share some of your knowledge?

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's all supplement information but in my opinion it's not redundant.

I think you probably should do both because they are for two different audiences. Your open graph data is for social networks (primarily Facebook) and your schema markup is for search engines. Obviously both are important and I personally think the advantage is with Schema because it's more universal but it really depends on how people are getting to you and that's going to depend on your internal marketing strategy and resources (i.e, you have 500,000 Facebook followers and you do hardcore Facebook ads then focus on Open Graph).

Meta tags are just a place to put information in the head of an HTML or XHTML document. You can include information in a page in a variety of ways.

Here's another post if you haven't seen it. [OpenGraph or Schema.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402528/opengraph-or-schema-org?rq=1)